# Meteor.js - mongodb $near $geometry GeoJSON Point coordinates longitude limit - Leaflet.js geoJson

Tags: mongodb, meteor, leaflet, geojson

I've got Meteor.js to talk with Leaflet.js to be able to display limited markers around the $near query of a "2dsphere" indexed Collection.

So I index my GeoJSON coordinates:

```
    Locations._ensureIndex({'geometry.coordinates':'2dsphere'});
```

It all works until I am using the $near operator to show markers beyond -90 to 90 longitude.

Latitude is bounding to -85 to 85, but longitude stops at -90 to 90 not -180 to 180 as expected.

So this works fine:

Leaflet map setView() to show the part of the map I want to place $near curson on:

```
window.map = L.map('map').setView([10,50],11);
```

Then the Server $near cursor - this works just as expected:

```
Meteor.publish('locations', function() {

return Locations.find({'geometry.coordinates':{ $near :
                       { $geometry :
                           { type : "Point" ,
                             coordinates: [10,50] } },
                         $maxDistance : 10000
           } 
           });

});
```

But as soon as I adjust the coordinates to

```
 [-33,151]
```

The leaflet map shows the location correctly, but the mongo $near throws an error:

```
$near requires a geojson point
```

Which is fair enough because that is an invalid point, but if I change it to:

```
  [151,-33]
```

Then the Leaflet map doesn't show the correct location and the $near operator doesn't work.

Why are the geoJSON longitude coordinate limited between -90 to 90 ? and how do I show and use the $near operator on a location :

```
   lat: -33 and long: 151
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it!

It had to do with a seemingly unrelated Leaflet.js way of adding a marker to the map.

So originally I used:

```
 var location=L.marker(mark.geometry.coordinates).addTo(window.map);
```

Changing this to:

```
 var location=L.geoJson(mark).addTo(window.map);
```

This meant that I could actually set the $near cursor to only show markers around my coordinates [-33,151]